# Infinite set which is Dedekind finite and Weierstrass compactness

Tags: general-topology, compactness, axiom-of-choice

Weierstrass compactness states that each infinite set has a limit point. Why Infinite set which is Dedekind finite with discrete metric not Weierstrass compact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that $x$ is a limit point of $A$ if and only if every neighborhood of $x$ meets $A$ on an infinite set. So in any case a discrete space will never be Weierstrass compact.

Simply because $\{x\}$ is a neighborhood of $x$. So no infinite set has any limit point. So the only way a discrete space can be Weierstrass is that it is finite, and the requirement is satisfied vacuously.

---

(The terminology is actually an accumulation point in some places, e.g. in Herrlich's "The Axiom of Choice", p.35)